# How do I fix this error "Error: An API error occurred: not_allowed_token_type" on Slack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

Recently, I've been creating Slack bot with Javascript. And then I got an error that is token type, which is given in `team.accessLogs()` funcntion is not allowed. Detailed error is below:

```
Error: An API error occurred: not_allowed_token_type
    at platformErrorFromResult (/bot-todo/node_modules/@slack/bolt/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/errors.js:56:33)
    at WebClient.apiCall (/bot-todo/node_modules/@slack/bolt/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/WebClient.js:181:56)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getIPAddress (file:///bot-todo/program-test.js:18:27) {       
  code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',
  data: { ok: false, error: 'not_allowed_token_type', response_metadata: {} }
}
```

Code:

```
'use strict';
import bolt from '@slack/bolt';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import fs from 'node:fs';
import readline from 'readline';
const rs = fs.createReadStream('./meaning-data.csv');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: rs});   
const app = new bolt.App(
  { token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, 
    appToken: process.env.SLACK_APP_TOKEN, 
    socketMode: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug' 
  });  
async function getIPAddress(n, page) {
  try {
    const userInformation = await app.client.team.accessLogs({
      token: "xxxx",
      before: 1701620221,
      count: n,
      page: page,
      limit: 1,
    });
    
    console.log(chalk.blue(userInformation));
  } catch(error){
    console.error(chalk.red(error));
  }
 }

getIPAddress('1', "12");
```

Up until now, I tried:

- Test whether this token is valid or not with auth.test api
- Given "admin" scope to the user scope to use `accessLogs()` function
- make sure other api that is working with same `SLACK_APP_TOKEN` in code.

**Images↓**

[admin user scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mORp.png)

[test with `auth.test()` api succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGMCa.png)

["not_allowed_token_type" error occured with api tester of `team.accessLogs()` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWiuD.png)

Based on the above facts, why test with `auth.test()` function succeed, although test with `team.accessLogs()` function failed?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include an example of your `.env` file? Obfuscate the values but please keep the formatting exactly the same

Comment: `before: 1701620221` suggests before `2023-12-03T16:17:01.000Z` ... it's more than 3 days after that time

Comment: Does your `.env` file not have a `SLACK_APP_TOKEN` entry? If so, I think that would be a pretty obvious issue

Comment: My `.env` file already included `SLACK_APP_TOKEN`, it's just hiding the part of `SLACK_APP_TOKEN`.

Comment: By the way, after you mentioned about `.env` file, I tried to replace latest `SLACK_APP_TOKEN` from old token, but consequently, I still couldn't solve this error.

Comment: Why test with tester of `auth.test()` function succeeds, although test with tester of `team.accessLogs()` function failed?

Comment: Just in case, when I made sure other api that is working with same `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN`, other api worked properly.

Comment: I suggest not sharing your token in a public location like stackoverflow, as it should be private!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `team.accessLogs` method is only available for the `user` token that has been granted the `admin` scope, not the `bot` token.  This is documented on the method's page here: https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs.

The user token starts with "xox**p**-" and not "xoxb-".

Comment: Finally, I could display the information using `team.accessLogs()` function. Thank you!

Comment: That's awesome! Consider upvoting and marking the answer as best answer!

Comment: How do I mark the answer as best answer?

Comment: You mean click the "accept" button to the left of your answer?

Comment: Yup exactly! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing `team_id` and bot token (xox**b**-*) to the request, but the documentation [says](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs) that 'The team_id is only relevant when using an org-level token.'. So perhaps try to omit the team_id or use the org-level token?

(sorry I don't have enough rep to comment)